# ¿Como poner un div padre sobre un elemento hijo?

Tags: html, css, rgba, opacity

lo quiero hacer es que la imagen se vea con una opacidad un poco mas oscura, entonces al div le di un fondo gris y quiero que este por encima de la imagen asi puedo conseguir el efecto que quiero, probe probando position relative al div y a la imagen un position absolute, despues les cambie de nuevo la position y hasta le puse a ambos z-index pero no estaría funcionando.

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0; 
}
.contenedor{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    z-index: 423423;
    width: 100%;
}

img{
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     width: 100%;
     
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="contenedor">

        <img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/351/384/1020/naturaleza-paisaje-rio-wallpaper-preview.jpg">
        
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías obtener el efecto de una manera más sencilla, te sugiero:

1. Si tu imagen está dentro del div, entonces no ocupas preocuparte por como colocarla con todas esas propiedades de CSS, siempre estará encima del div.
2. Puedes aprovechar para cambiar la opacidad de la imagen que está encima del div, entre mas transparente sea más adquirirá el tono del color del fondo del div contenedor.

Mira lo corto que es el código ahora:

```js
const imagerino = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]

function opacityHandle(elem) {
  imagerino.style.opacity = elem.value;
}
```

```css
.contenedor {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}

img {
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="range" id="opacidad" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" onchange="opacityHandle(this)">
  <div class="contenedor">
    <img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/351/384/1020/naturaleza-paisaje-rio-wallpaper-preview.jpg">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

También te recomiendo que le eches un ojo a [los filtros](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) de CSS. ¡Suerte programando!

### UPDATE

Slider interactivo, solo porque tenía un poco de tiempo libre.

Comment: Muchas Gracias me estaba volviendo loco, si es mucho mas sencillo :D

Answer (score 2):

Un camino mas corto sería usar la propiedad [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/filter), con esta propiedad puedes lograr diferentes efectos de color y desenfoque, es muy util a la hora de trabajar con imagenes en css:

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0; 
}
.contenedor{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    z-index: 423423;
    width: 100%;
}

img{
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     width: 100%;
     filter: opacity(50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="contenedor">

        <img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/351/384/1020/naturaleza-paisaje-rio-wallpaper-preview.jpg">
        
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Una aclaración: la opacidad no es ni más ni menos oscura, es la cantidad de transparencia que se aplica a un elemento.

Si quieres un elemento totalmente opaco pondrás `opacity: 1`, pero si quieres que sea algo transparente podrás variar ese número hasta 0, que significa que el objeto es transparente.

Aclarado este punto, parece que quieres ennegrecer la imagen. Eso puedes hacerlo de dos formas:

### 1. Aplicando directamente un filtro en la imagen

```css
.contenedor > img {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<p>Imagen original</p>
<div>
  <img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/351/384/1020/naturaleza-paisaje-rio-wallpaper-preview.jpg">
</div>

<p>Imagen con filtro <em>brightness</em> al 50%</p>
<div class="contenedor">
  <img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/351/384/1020/naturaleza-paisaje-rio-wallpaper-preview.jpg">
</div>
```

2. Añadiendo un elemento de color con transparencia por encima de la imagen

Esta técnica se conoce por el nombre inglés *Overlay*

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div > img {
  position: relative;
  /* Medidas arbitrarias para el div */
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
}

img {
  /* la imagen ocupa el div */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/351/384/1020/naturaleza-paisaje-rio-wallpaper-preview.jpg">
</div>
```

En mi ejemplo yo he creado un pseudo elemento after que es el que tiene el fondo semitransparente (verde para que veas el efecto).